# How to control how JSON_ARRAYAGG orders results

Tags: mysql, json

I am testing MySQL `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_ARRAYAGG` functions in order to move some application expensive processes to SQL stored functions.

In the following e-commerce application example, I am trying to retrieve a user's cart, not as a resultset of rows from the cart_items table, but as a JSON string containing all the needed information for a Javascript call back function to render the cart.

I have a `cart` table holding the general cart information

```
create table user_cart (
  cart_id  integer unsigned primary key,
  user_id  integer unsigned not null,
);
```

and a `cart_item` detail table,

```
create table cart_item (
  cart_item_id  integer unsigned primary key auto_increment,
  cart_id       integer unsigned not null,
  product_id    integer unsigned not null,

  qty           integer unsigned not null,
  ref           varchar(15) not null,

  -- total
  base          double default 0.0,
  tax           double default 0.0,
  tax_pct       double default 0.0,
  total         double default 0.0,

  foreign key (cart_id) references user_cart(cart_id),
);
```

Inserted the following data into the tables

```
insert into user_cart(user_id, cart_id) values
(9001, 30201),
(9001, 30202);
(9001, 30203),
(9001, 30245),
(9001, 30300),
(9001, 30344);

insert into cart_item(cart_id, qty, product_id, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) values
(30201, 10, 90000, 'BBB-90000', 12, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52),
(30201, 20, 33333, 'JKL-33333', 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538),
(30201, 10, 12211, 'BBB-12211', 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405),
(30201, 1,  12821, 'XXX-12821', 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042),
(30201, 5,  10000, 'DLO-10000', 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228),
(30201, 10, 12345, 'XXX-12345', 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395),
(30201, 1,  11590, 'DLO-11590', 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025),
(30201, 1,  45000, 'NKN-45000', 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552),
(30201, 1,  14999, 'DLO-14999', 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299),
(30201, 3,  98700, 'XYI-98700', 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207),
(30201, 1,  10391, 'BBB-10391', 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745),
(30201, 1,  11021, 'DLO-11021', 4, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84),
(30201, 2,  11884, 'BBB-11884', 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022);
```

Then, I tried to retrieve the cart items of user `30201` I wrote the following select sentence

```
select json_arrayagg(jobj) from (
  select json_array(product_id, qty, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) as jobj
  from cart_item where cart_id = 30201
) as jarray\G
```

that returns

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
json_arrayagg(jobj): [[90000, 10, "BBB-90000", 12.0, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52], [33333, 20, "JKL-33333", 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538], [12211, 10, "BBB-12211", 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405], [12821, 1, "XXX-12821", 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042], [10000, 5, "DLO-10000", 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228], [12345, 10, "XXX-12345", 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395], [11590, 1, "DLO-11590", 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025], [45000, 1, "NKN-45000", 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552], [14999, 1, "DLO-14999", 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299], [98700, 3, "XYI-98700", 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207], [10391, 1, "BBB-10391", 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745], [11021, 1, "DLO-11021", 4.0, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84], [11884, 2, "BBB-11884", 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022]]
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Scan the result and you will find that products are listed in the insertion order: 90000, 33333, 12211, 12821, 10000, 12345,.... If you try to revert this order using an `order by` clause, it will be ignored.

```
select json_arrayagg(jobj) from (   
  select json_array(product_id, qty, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) as jobj   
  from cart_item where cart_id = 30201 order by product_id 
) as jarray\G
```

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
json_arrayagg(jobj): [[90000, 10, "BBB-90000", 12.0, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52], [33333, 20, "JKL-33333", 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538], [12211, 10, "BBB-12211", 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405], [12821, 1, "XXX-12821", 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042], [10000, 5, "DLO-10000", 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228], [12345, 10, "XXX-12345", 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395], [11590, 1, "DLO-11590", 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025], [45000, 1, "NKN-45000", 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552], [14999, 1, "DLO-14999", 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299], [98700, 3, "XYI-98700", 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207], [10391, 1, "BBB-10391", 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745], [11021, 1, "DLO-11021", 4.0, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84], [11884, 2, "BBB-11884", 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022]]
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Where is it expected to put the `order by` clause to take effect?
Is there any modifier to `JSON_ARRAYAGG` as it appears to be in Oracle DB?

Comment: Technically it is unordered, correct?

Comment: Well, it follows a "natural order", the one I commented before: the order of growing cart_item_id.

Comment: What I want to do is change that order by any other more convenient.

Comment: I have manually trimmed many of the superfluous columns in the tables. In case any error occurs testing the code ask me, please

Comment: On another topic:  Don't use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for monetary values.

Comment: [Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) claims that *The order of elements in this array is undefined.* The `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function have no such parameter as inner ORDER BY clause, so you cannot affect on the result's components order. The only way to solve your task is to build the JSON value's text in the order you need using text processing technique (using string functions and operators). Moreover, you may NOT to cast the final result to JSON (output field format must be a string), or the parts order will alter.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the detailed answer. I am using group_concat() and struggling with its size limitations

Comment: Maximal length is limited by `group_concat_max_len` and `max_allowed_packet` variables. Adjust them.

Comment: I'm not sure about the version of MySQL used by you, but since version 8.0.2 there is support for [12.21 Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) and you can evaluate ideas like the one shown in the following [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8230a9c46aed4acfd11964bad5e5f87).

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you @wchiquito

Answer (score 2):

This is a fun one, if you've got a hard functional requirement to do the ordering in the database. Then this works, you can use MySQL's "feature" against itself by first inserting the data into a temporary table in the order you want it.

```
drop temporary table if exists temp_results;
create temporary table temp_results
select
    json_array(product_id, qty, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) as jobj
from cart_item
where cart_id = 30201
    order by
    product_id;
```

Then you can do the json_arrayagg func back out and it's in the order you want.

```
select
    json_arrayagg(jobj)
from temp_results tr;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` in tandem, though you'll have to be aware of certain limitations of `GROUP_CONCAT` namely the maximum length allowed by it (`group_concat_max_len`).

Using your example,

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
  '[', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_ARRAY(
      product_id, 
      qty, 
      ref, 
      base, 
      tax, 
      tax_pct, 
      total
    ) 
    ORDER BY product_id
  ), 
  ']'
)
FROM cart_item 
WHERE cart_id = 30201;
```

Produces

```
[
[10000, 5, "DLO-10000", 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228],
[10391, 1, "BBB-10391", 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745],
[11021, 1, "DLO-11021", 4, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84],
[11590, 1, "DLO-11590", 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025],
[11884, 2, "BBB-11884", 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022],
[12211, 10, "BBB-12211", 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405],
[12345, 10, "XXX-12345", 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395],
[12821, 1, "XXX-12821", 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042],
[14999, 1, "DLO-14999", 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299],
[33333, 20, "JKL-33333", 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538],
[45000, 1, "NKN-45000", 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552],
[90000, 10, "BBB-90000", 12, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52],
[98700, 3, "XYI-98700", 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207]
]
```