# Do multiple MYSQL json_arrayagg(s) preserve order?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

```sql
select media_id, 
 json_arrayagg(artist_id) as artist_ids, 
 json_arrayagg(role) as role_ids
from x_media__artist xma group by media_id
```

Hi guys, do artist_ids and role_ids preserve their order as they were in the group?
For example, if (medium_id,artist_id,role_id) with (1,1,1) and (1,2,2) then
the query above always returns 1 [1,2] [1,2] or 1 [2,1] [2,1] but NEVER 1 [1,2] [2,1]?

Hi, after rechecking MYSQL API, there is absolutely a better solution:

```sql
select media_id, 
 json_arrayagg(json_array(artist_id, role)) as artist_role_ids
from x_media__artist xma group by media_id
```

but I am still curious about the answer!

Comment: I think you have to use group_concat to control the order which by the way it is not an optimal way. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572309/how-to-order-by-a-json-object-in-mysql) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242916/how-to-control-how-json-arrayagg-orders-results) which is the same question

Comment: @ErgestBasha I am not attempting fully control the order, but two list orders should by the same permutation. 0.0 Let me check the question u mentioned first

Comment: *two list orders should by the same permutation* This cannot be guaranteed. So the code which puts matched values into single array and then aggregates these arrays is preferrable because it guarantees the matching.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Akina. I am going to close this question by self-answer.

The following code will !NOT! guarantee the same permutation for artist_ids and role_ids by the link from @Ergest Basha: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg.

```sql
select media_id, 
 json_arrayagg(artist_id) as artist_ids, 
 json_arrayagg(role) as role_ids
from x_media__artist xma group by media_id
```

And the following code will probably work as expected as suggested by @Akina.

```sql
select media_id, 
 json_arrayagg(json_array(artist_id, role)) as artist_role_ids
from x_media__artist xma group by media_id
```